# How to append parameters to URL before page starts loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Chrome, I'm looking to detect in a page URL is going to be on `example.com`'s domain, and if it is, before loading, append `foo=bar` as a parameter and load that instead.

I've found that I can access when the Omnibar has been [submitted here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html#event-onInputEntered), but it seems like it'd load the original URL anyways, and while that's *alright* it's twice the bandwidth I feel is necessary. It's not a problem when it's only one page, but it's a change that needs to happen on every page in an site, so double the bandwidth definitely becomes an issue.

Currently, it works to detect if the URL is going to be `example.com` and is submitted, then call `window.stop()` and then set `location.href` to `example.com/&?foo=bar` but that doesn't seem ideal.

In short, the user goes to `http://www.example.com` and then the script changes it to `http://www.example.com/&?foo=bar` before loading  the original link.

Comment: Are you looking solely at client-side solutions, or can this be done at the server?

Comment: @MikeBrant Client side, as I'm created a Chrome Extension for public use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) API, in particular the following method:

> onBeforeRequest (optionally synchronous)
>
> Fires when a request is about to occur. This event is sent before any TCP connection is made and can be used to cancel or redirect requests.

Comment: This actually looks like exactly what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.location.search = "foo=bar"
```

may be this helps.

Comment: Now I'm not sure, but I was under the impression that just find that string in the bar

Comment: what do you mean, i can't get you.

Comment: Never heard of `window.search` Please post a link explaining it. Do you mean `location.search`?

Comment: That only returns a string, doesn't actually change the URL, I don't think.

Comment: @TankorSmash In Chrome, it is not read-only. But the question is about how to trigger that before the page starts loading, isn't it?